# AVR TWI/I2C Not Responding

Tags: avr, atmega, interrupts, twi

I use `Twi` module of `AVR` `Atmega168` to talk to `DS1307`.

`Twi` works on the interrupt mode.

It works fine for a few hours and then stops, hopefully losing `Twi` interrupts further.

Is there any way to fix/resolve/work around this issue.

Any practical tips would be of great help.

Comment: Can you please add the source code? It sounds like it locks up after one unsuccessful transfer.

Comment: @venny, I would add source code later. Can you please elaborate on what you said?

Comment: I meant that the software probably can not cope with accidentally corrupted frames and recover after the error is gone.

Comment: @venny: So how can I recover from such things, disable TWI (TWEN=0) and renable? A repeated start does not seem to help.

Comment: Disabling TWI will not help, because the slave might be errorneously holding SDA low. You have to manually send clock pulses on SCL until SDA gets high. Then you can do repeated start.

Comment: @venny: Is it a standard approach? How to go about it, like, how the port pins must be configured, input/output?

Comment: I am not sure if it is standard, but it is true. Once I was dealing with something similar. When you reset a MCU in the middle of transaction, I2C slave will still have half a byte in its output shift register. When the most recent bit is 0, SDA is held at 0 and that means asserting start or stop is impossible. On AVRs, turning off the TWI will revert the pins to GPIO mode. Open collector output can be emulated by PORTxy at constant 0 and toggling DDRxy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17041/discussion-between-babu-james-and-venny).

Answer (score 3):

It might already irrelevant for you but it might help others, I was experiencing the same issue, in the datasheet the following is stated:

> To recover from a bus error, the TWSTO Flag must set and TWINT must be cleared by writing a logic one to it. This causes the TWI to enter the not addressed Slave mode and to clear the TWSTO Flag (no other bits in TWCR are affected). The SDA and SCL lines are released, and no STOP condition is transmitted.

So I just added the following line of code to my error handling routine (verify TWSR values):

```
TWCR = (1 << TWINT)|(1 << TWSTO);
```

And so far it works like a charm.